# Append string of column index to DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project using Learning to Rank. Below is the example dataset format (taken from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/letor-learning-rank-information-retrieval/). The first column is the rank, second column is query id, and the followings are `[feature number]:[feature value]`

```
1008 qid:10 1:0.004356 2:0.080000 3:0.036364 4:0.000000 … 46:0.00000

1007 qid:10 1:0.004901 2:0.000000 3:0.036364 4:0.333333 … 46:0.000000

1006 qid:10 1:0.019058 2:0.240000 3:0.072727 4:0.500000 … 46:0.000000
```

Right now, I am successfully convert my data into this following format in `Pandas.DataFrame`.

```
10  qid:354714443278337 3500 1 122.0 156.0 13.0 1698.0 1840.0 92.28260 ...
...
```

The first two column is already fine. What I need next is appending feature number to the remaining columns (e.g. first feature from `3500` become `1:3500`)

I know I can append a string to columns by using this following command.

```
df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
```

Look at the first feature, `3500`, is located at column index 2, so what I can think of is appending `column index - 1` for each column. How do I append the string based on the column number?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrame.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html) for add columns names from right side and [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select from second column to end:

```
print (df)
    0                    1     2  3      4      5     6       7       8  \
0  10  qid:354714443278337  3500  1  122.0  156.0  13.0  1698.0  1840.0   
1  10  qid:354714443278337  3500  1  122.0  156.0  13.0  1698.0  1840.0   

         9  
0  92.2826  
1  92.2826  

df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(str).radd(':').radd((df.columns[2:] - 1).astype(str))
print (df)
    0                    1       2    3        4        5       6         7  \
0  10  qid:354714443278337  1:3500  2:1  3:122.0  4:156.0  5:13.0  6:1698.0   
1  10  qid:354714443278337  1:3500  2:1  3:122.0  4:156.0  5:13.0  6:1698.0   

          8          9  
0  7:1840.0  8:92.2826  
1  7:1840.0  8:92.2826
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried in small dataset and this approach works. However, I am working with large dataset and got MemoryError. I am just wondering, is there more efficient approach?

Comment: @DarrenChristopher - What is size of DataFrame?

Comment: it's 50K rows and 1.5K columns. Actually the total data I have is around 440K rows, but as I got MemoryError frequently, I decided to divide 50K-ish then write to file and appending it afterwards.If there is more efficient approach it would be helpful. If no, I guess I should try dividing it less than 50K per transformation process

Comment: @DarrenChristopher - Not so easy. Little modification should be `df.iloc[:, 2:] = np.arange(1, len(df.columns)-1).astype(str) + (':' + df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(str))`, but not sure if less memory consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate the columns

```
df['new_col'] = df[df.columns[3]].astype(str) + ':' + df[df.columns[2]].astype(str)
```

This will output a new column in your df named `new_col`. Now you can either delete the unnecessary columns.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, the third column will also need to be transformed into similar format (i.e. 2:1). In complete form, they will be (10 qid:354714443278337 1:3500 2:1 3:122.0 4:156.0 5:13.0 6:1698.0 7:1840.0 8:92.28260 ...

Comment: same can be achieved using the code mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to dictionary and then read it again as pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'rank': [1008, 1007, 1006], 'column':['qid:10 1:0.004356 2:0.080000 3:0.036364 4:0.000000',\
                    'qid:10 1:0.004901 2:0.000000 3:0.036364 4:0.333333',\
                    'qid:10 1:0.019058 2:0.240000 3:0.072727 4:0.500000']} )

def putquotes(x):
    x1 = x.split(":")
    return "'" + x1[0] +"':" + x1[1]

def putcommas(x):
    x1 = x.split()
    return "{" + ",".join([putquotes(t) for t in x1]) + "}"

import ast
df1 = [ast.literal_eval(putcommas(x)) for x in df['column'].tolist()]
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df1)], axis=1)
```